# if sum two series with nonnegative terms converge prove the sum of multiplication of their sum also converges

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

let $a_n$ and $b_n$ be nonnegative. and $\sum a_n + \sum b_n <\infty$. Prove $\sum a_nb_n$ converges.
I know examples of pairs of divergent/convergent series whose sum or product is convergent. but I can not distinguish any pattern to help me think of proof for this exercise.
actually I am studying series, and I am trying to generalize some concepts of possible scenarios at which convergence or divergence of series is guaranteed. 
I would appreciate any help with proving the statement above.

Answer (score 2):

Since $\sum b_n<\infty$ the series is convergent and we get $\lim b_n =0$. So there exists a constant $n_0\in\mathbb{N}$ so that $\forall n\geq n_0: b_n\leq1$. So for all $n\geq n_0$ we get $a_n b_n \leq a_n$. By the direct comparison test with the series $\sum\limits_{n\geq n_0} a_n<\infty$ we get the convergence of $$\sum\limits_{n\geq n_0} a_n b_n.$$ Since there are only finte elements left, the series converges.

Comment: Does this mean sum of two series with non negative terms converges only if both series are convergent?

Comment: Yes! Since all terms are non negative you get $0\leq \sum b_n$ and therefore you can estimate upwards $\sum a_n \leq \sum a_n + \sum b_n <\infty$. Since all terms $a_n$ are non negative $k\mapsto \sum_{n=1}^{k} a_n$ is a monotonously growing and bounded sequence, thus it is convergent.
The opposite direction is obviously I think.

Comment: If you meant by 'sum of two series' this: $\sum (a_n+b_n)$ you can use the same argument, since $\sum a_n \leq\sum (a_n+b_n).$

Answer (score 1):

If $\sum_na_n+\sum_nb_n$ converges, then so does $\sum_n(a_n+b_n)$. The terms of this series are non-negative, so $\sum_n(a_n+b_n)^2$ also converges, as do $\sum_na_n^2$ and $\sum_nb_n^2$. Now consider $\sum_n(a_n+b_n)^2-\sum_na_n^2-\sum_nb_n^2$.